# Not able to format date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I want to format `billDetail.invoiceDate` as `dd-mm`

my code is

```
$.each(data.billDetails, function(position, billDetail) {

      if (billDetail.invoiceDate) {
             //I tried
             var dat = (billDetail.invoiceDate).format("dd-mm");//Showing  error
             chartData.labels.push(dat); 
      } else {

        chartData.labels.push(''); 
      }

      chartData.datasets[0].data.push(billDetail.totalBills);
      chartData.datasets[1].data.push(billDetail.totalAmount);
    });
```

Showing  error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functiondashboard.action:221
 (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 n.extend.eachdashboard.action:218 
 $.ajax.successjquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 jjquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 k.fireWithjquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 
   xjquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 (anonymous function)
```

My data as given in console is

```
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-25T00:00:00 4 1545
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-24T00:00:00 6 24497
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-23T00:00:00 1 114
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-22T00:00:00 1 114
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-18T00:00:00 5 4916
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-13T00:00:00 7 29040
dashboard.action:191 2014-11-01T00:00:00 4 7317
dashboard.action:191 2014-10-31T00:00:00 7 53061
dashboard.action:191 2014-10-30T00:00:00 1 114
```

Comment: is `billDetail.invoiceDate` a date object or string.. also there is no `.format()` function for date object... you need to use some third party libraries to do that

Comment: @ArunPJohny plese se updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `getDate()` and `getMonth()` [Date Object Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) :

Your `billDetail.invoiceDate` is a String so make it a Date then manage it.

```
var d = new Date(billDetail.invoiceDate);
var dat = d.getDate()+"-"+parseInt(d.getMonth()+1);
```

This is [the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktfLtunL/4/).

That should do it.

Comment: Bear in mind that JavaScript months are 0-indexed, whilst days are 1-indexed.

Comment: Showing  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @chridam Yes, in fact you are right I edited the code.

Comment: @xrcwrn: it's working, take a look at [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktfLtunL/2/), maybe your `billDetail.invoiceDate` is not correct

Comment: My console log is  `ObjectbillDetails: Array[18]0: ObjectinvoiceDate: "2014-11-25T00:00:00"totalAmount: 1545totalBills: 4`

Comment: Yes your fiddle code is working please see what is the problem with my data edited in question

Comment: @xrcwrn I see, the problem is that it's a String and not a Date take a look at my Edit.